# Remove duplicate entries in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a few thousand rows. The table contains two columns, `name` and `email`. I have several duplicate rows, for example:

- John Smith  |   john@smith.com
- John Smith  |   john@smith.com
- Erica Smith |   erica@smith.com
- Erica Smith |   erica@smith.com

What would be the easiest way to delete all duplicate results. For example, such that the table's content would  = `SELECT name, DISTINCT(email) FROM table`.

Comment: one way to do is using primary key. so you have primary key in your table or just name and email only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pretty easily do this by selecting that query into another table, then renaming it to replace the original.

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `name` varchar(255), 
  `email` varchar(255), 
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`));
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT `name`, DISTINCT(`email`) FROM `table`;
RENAME TABLE `table` TO `table1`;
RENAME TABLE `table2` TO `table`;
```

Note that this `CREATE` should be adjusted to your actual table format.  I added the unique key on the email field as a suggestion on how you would prevent duplicates in the first place.

Alternatively, you could loop over this

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `email` IN (
  SELECT `email` FROM `table` GROUP BY `email` HAVING count(*) > 1
) LIMIT 1
```

Which would delete one duplicate record per call.  The importance of the limit is to not remove both rows for any duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to copy all distinct values into a new table:

```
select distinct *
into NewTable
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id 
NOT IN
(SELECT A.id
FROM 
(
SELECT name,MAX(id) AS id
FROM table
GROUP BY name
) A
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an auto-increment field to the table.  I believe that when you add it, it will be 'backfilled' for you.  Since MySql doesn't allow a delete based on a subquery against the same table, the easiest solution is to then dump the whole dataset into a temptable for use in processing.  Assuming you called the new field RowId and the temp table tempTable, you can then use code like this:

```
DELETE FROM NameAndEmail
LEFT JOIN 
(     SELECT name, email, Max(RowId) as MaxRowId 
      FROM temptable 
      GROUP BY name, email
) as MaxId
WHERE NameAndEmail.Email = MaxId.Email
     and NameAndEmail.Name = MaxId.Name
     and NameAndEmail.RowId <> MaxId.RowId
```

Answer (score 1):

### Add a unique index

The simplest way to clean up a table with duplicate data - is to *just* add a unique index:

```
set session old_alter_table=1;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (name, email);
```

Pay particular attention to the first sql statement, without it [the IGNORE flag is ignored](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344) and the alter table statement will fail with an error.