# Removing duplicate rows (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I have about 75,000 entries/rows, and after using

```
SELECT WWW, COUNT(*) c FROM pmd_listings GROUP BY WWW HAVING c > 1;
```

I have discovered I have about 9000 duplicates (based on just the one column, probably a little less in actuality). I can only use group by with aggregate functions (not entirely sure what that means) but I want to remove duplicates if the rows match in these columns (to be sure they're duplicates)

`"friendly_url"` `"www"` and `"listing_zip"` Inside the table `"pmd_listings"`.

I tried running this simulation:

> https://pastebin.com/QWCb5jJ4

But I get the following error:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'c1.id' in 'where clause'
```

How can I acomplish this? Help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724055/delete-with-table-alias-in-mysql

Comment: Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That works @Adrien, however It's only checking against one column, would adding a second column after the first in the select field work?

Comment: Yes of course, your error was the way you declared your alias, replacing `DELETE FROM pmd_listings c1` with `DELETE c1 FROM pmd_listings c1` should do the trick

Comment: Check with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880068/remove-duplicate-entries-in-a-mysql-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias `c1` needs to be referenced between DELETE and FROM for MySql.
Try this way:

```
DELETE FROM pmd_listings
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT t.id FROM ( 
    SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM pmd_listings
    GROUP BY friendly_url, www, listing_zip
  ) t
)
```

Comment: I'm now being told  **#1093 - You can't specify target table 'c1' for update in FROM clause**. But I understand, the second part was kind of redundant.

Comment: This seems really promising, when running simulation it's giving me Matched rows: 3265. There should be about 9000 when just going off the www so those other entries must be different in some way. This will work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join` with `delete`:

```
delete pl
    from pmd_listings pl left join
         (select pl2.friendly_url, pl2.www, pl2.listing_zip, min(id) as min_id
          from pmd_listings pl2
          group by pl2.friendly_url, pl2.www, pl2.listing_zip
         ) pl2
         on pl2.id = pl.id
    where pl2.id is null;
```

The aggregation subquery finds all minimum ids for the combinations of your three columns.  The `left join` finds matches to those ids and the `where` means that all non-matching rows -- that is, all but the first row -- are deleted.